# How to convert existing gz (gzip) files to rsyncable

Tags: rsync, gzip

I am using rsync to back up a repository that contains many gz files including many new ones each day. The rsync backup proceeds more slowly than it should because these gz files are not built with gzip's --rsyncable option (which makes gz files much more 'rsync-friendly' without significantly increasing their size or affecting their compatibility). And I can't fix the problem at creation time because the files are generated by a python script (rdiff-backup) which uses python's gzip module and this does not support an equivalent to gzip's --rsyncable.

So before running rsync I can identify any new gz files in the source data (i.e. new since the last time rsync was run). Now I want to 're-gzip' these files so that they are gzipped in rsyncable-format. Then I can run rsync from the optimised source.

I think this means running each file through gunzip and then gzip --rsyncable but I am not too sure how to do this in a way that won't risk losing data or metadata. Suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: The only way `--rsyncable` should matter is if the files get changed between runs and `rsync` tries to send the changes. New files don't care if they're rsyncable or not, because `rsync` has to send all the data anyway. Are the files being changed between rsync runs?

Comment: Good point. Actually I'm not sure, I will check into that. Let's assume for now that yes the contents of some gz files do get changed.

Comment: The best thing I can think of is to run a script that checks for new files, un-gzips them, then gzips them again with `--rsyncable`.

Comment: I agree that if the files don't change, this shouldn't be an issue.  In particular, for speed make sure you skip checksumming based on time by preserving times using the `-a` flag.  Also, my version of gzip doesn't have an `--rsyncable` flag, but it does come with a program called `znew` that could probably be used for what you need.

Comment: It turns out that, as Tom thought, the gz files created by rdiff-backup don't change once created and so using `--rsyncable` wouldn't help. I was hoping for a line of code or short script that would safely unpack a gz archive and repack it using `--rsyncable`. But it's just an academic question for me now.

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /bin/bash

set -euo pipefail

##  TOKEN's creation time marks the time since last recompression
TOKEN=.lastRecompression   

if [ -f ${TOKEN} ]
then
    find -name '*.gz' -cnewer "${TOKEN}"
else
    # Process all compressed files if there is no token.
    find -name '*.gz'
fi | while read f
do
    # Do it in two steps
    gunzip < "$f" | gzip --rsyncable > "$f.tmp"

    # Preserve attributes
    cp "$f" "$f.tmp" --attributes-only

    # and rename atomically.
    # set -e ensures that a problem in the previous step 
    # will stop the full script. 
    mv -v "$f.tmp" "$f"
done

# Update the token
touch ${TOKEN}
```

Comment: By doing `gunzip | gzip`, you're loosing the uncompressed name and time as stored in the gz file (and seen with `gzip -vNl`)

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas: You are right: if this information is relevant (it has never been relevant for me), we are losing it.  Maybe the best solution would be for gunzip to directly support this re-compression. It could pass all metadata internally.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Do you know any to do it losslessly?